# VBA - Copy values in different cells every button's click

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a small spreadsheet where the purpose is to insert a value, associated to a depth, and click a validation button which copies such value in a cell on a different sheet, clears the inserted value on the original sheet and, at the same time, updates the depth (+0.20 step) for next value to be inserted.
This is what I created so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Sheets("DPSH").Range("B2").Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DPSH (Totale)").Range("B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Sheets("DPSH").Range("B2").ClearContents
        Sheets("DPSH").Range("A2").Value = Range("A2") + 0.2
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

It works fine for the first value but here is the challenge. I have to copy, with the second button's click, the second value to a different cell, (Sheet "DPSH Totale", cell "B3"), then to copy, with the third button's click, the third value to a different cell, (Sheet "DPSH Totale", cell "B4"), etc.
I'm sorry if the request would appear silly but I'm not really a pro with VBA.
Thanks in advance for your kind suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work if your requirement is to copy to the next empty cell at or under B2

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    Dim c As Range, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = Sheets("DPSH")
    
    Set c = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DPSH (Totale)").Range("B2")
    'find the first empty cell to copy to
    Do While Len(c.Value) > 0
        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
    c.Value = ws.Range("B2").Value
    ws.Range("B2").ClearContents
    ws.Range("A2").Value = ws.Range("A2").Value + 0.2
    
End Sub
```